# Web.config file in Github with sensitive data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, github, msbuild, github-actions

I want to know in what ways you are working with GitHub, when you have sensitive data in `web.config` (such as logins to databases and etc.), need to share with other team members about changes in this file, and need to have automatically builds with GitHub actions.

I am looking for a solution how to work with that because we are migrating from TFS to Github.

Where are you storing the `web.config` file? In GitHub as a template? And then building some template fields are filling up from secrets?
Have some pre-push hooks? Or some other way?

Thanks for the advice

Comment: I don't suggest you storing sensitive data inside web.config.  I suggest you could use Azure key vault or else. Or you don't add it and laterly add it in inside appsetting.json in production enviroment.

Comment: Read about GitHub secrets management and you will see how others work this out.

Comment: You may find "[Using secrets in GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions)" useful.